# Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. How do we show $Y=\{(t, t^2, t^3) \mid t \in k\}$ is an algebraic set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

There is an exercise in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* with says to show that $Y=\{(t, t^2, t^3) \mid t \in k\}$ is an affine variety of dimension $1$.

But I actually don't even know how to show that it is algebraic set.

The easiest polynomials I thought of that vanish on $Y$ are: $x^2-y, x^3-z, y^3-z^2$.

**How do we show that $Y$ is affine algebraic set?**

How do we come up with the polynomials to define $Y$?

How would we go about showing that $Y$ is the zero set of these polynomials?

Comment: Is the third polynomial you write necessary? Consider the affine algebraic set determined by the first two polynomials. You exactly get Y (by x=t)

Comment: How do we know $Y=Z(x^2-y, x^3-z)$? How do we know that there isn't some point $(a,b,c) \in Z(x^2-y, x^3-z)$ that is not in $Y$?

Comment: Pick such a point and show that it must be in $Y$. Given $(a,b,c)\in Z(x^2-y,x^3-z)$, can you show that $(a,b,c)=(t,t^2,t^3)$ for some $t\in k$?

Comment: @KReiser I see now. If $(a,b,c) \in Z(x^2-y, x^3-z)$, then $a^2-b=0$ and $a^3-c=0$. So, $(a,b,c)=(a, a^2, a^3)$. So, $(a,b,c) \in Y$. Also, $(t, t^2, t^3)$ vanishes under $x^2-y$ and $x^3-z$. So, $Y \subset Z(x^2-y, x^3-z)$. So, $Y=Z(x^2-y, x^3-z)$.